# Recreating Liferay Site Pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

we have several users that have personal public pages.

What we want to do is to recreate their personal pages because they have been assigned the wrong ones (using the wrong Site Template).
So we want to :

1) Delete the old User pages

2) Create them again using a Site Template.

In the end the users should have the "new" Pages.

Is there any way to do this programmatically ?

I have posted the same question in the liferay message board:

https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/87001817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might need some adoption to API changes, the old and ancient SevenCogs code (part of Liferay CE up to 6.0 AFAIK) might help you doing so. The principles still hold well, and the last adoption has been [made by James Falkner](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) to 6.1 - to detect & fix the differences to 6.2 shouldn't be that hard. Alternatively look up the original sevencogs-hook implementation, which is extremely well readable (a lot of code, but linear, no complexity: It's a single script that runs exactly once. No conditionals, top-to-bottom)